# Error with Geocoder.getFromLocationName method

Tags: java, android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-geocoder

I am trying to use geocoding to get the latitudes/longitudes of a given place by passing a street address. This is my code :

```
 String addr = "Shop No. 2, Payal Cinema, Old Delhi Road, Sec-14, Gurgaon";                             
 Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
 List<Address> addressList = null;
 try {

          addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(addr, 10);

     } catch (IOException e) {}
 Address address = addressList.get(0);
 if(address.hasLatitude() && address.hasLongitude()){
 lat = address.getLatitude();
 lon = address.getLongitude();
 }
```

The error is in the call to gecoder.getFromLocationName(addr,10) ( I checked it through System.out.println;things don't get printed to the logcat after that line)

Here is the stack trace from LogCat:

```
 W/dalvikvm(630): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{apt.kangkan/apt.kangkan.AddrMarkrsonMapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at apt.kangkan.AddrMarkrsonMapActivity.onCreate(AddrMarkrsonMapActivity.java:76)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
 E/AndroidRuntime(630):     ... 11 more
 I/dalvikvm(630): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
 I/dalvikvm(630): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

you can see there is a java.lang.NullPointerException. i don't know why its arising. Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually latitude and  longitude not found for your address please check "addressList" is null or not if it is not null then  continue like below..

```
 if (addressList == null)
    {
             Log.d(TAG,"Latitude and longitude not found");
    }
     else {
     Address location = addressList.get(0);
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
     longitude = location.getLongitude();
     }
```

Comment: i did try this. and i feel this is the problem too. but nothing is coming up on the LogCat even after doing the check mentioned above

Comment: Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault()); instead of this statement use this Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this);

Comment: well it does work for some addresses, doesn't for others. moreover it is not giving the exact latitude/longitude of the places. can you suggest any way (in the code) to increase gps accuracy in my app?

Comment: use this getFromLocationName(addr, 5); let me know any difference.

Comment: I used this. But no difference. same wrong latitudes and longitudes of the same place

Comment: can you send place and lat ,long wt you got.

Comment: addr = "307, 3rd Floor, F-Block Shopping Plaza, South City-2, Gurgaon". the lat/longs' i get : 28.427263,77.05965

Comment: just see following links and tel me which one showing correct.

Comment: @ http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=28.427263,77.05965&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=-5-8T4O5B9DorQfNsenODQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=3&ved=0CBYQ_AUoAg

Comment: second one @ http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=307,+3rd+Floor,+F-Block+Shopping+Plaza,+South+City-2,+Gurgaon&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=DKC8T9DXLo3prQe7nbWkDQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=3&ved=0CEQQ_AUoAg

Comment: actually both are correct. the problem is with google maps. the address i gave you is not where google map shows it is. it is somewhere else. no doubt the la/longs were pointing in the wrong place. fault is with g-maps

Comment: through the geocoder. passing addresses and getting lat/longs. then using overlays to mark them